# linking into the tensorflow libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, compilation, static-linking

I am writing a custom OP for `tensorflow`.  My operation is a linear algebra type thing, so I have been using the boilerplate from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/00fad90125b18b80fe054de1055770cfb8fe4ba3/tensorflow/core/kernels/self_adjoint_eig_op.cc#L32) to implement a similar thing:

```
template <class Scalar>
class FooOp : public ::tensorflow::LinearAlgebraOp<Scalar> {
 public:
  typedef LinearAlgebraOp<Scalar> Base;
  explicit FooOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : Base(context) {}

  using TensorShapes = typename Base::TensorShapes;
  using Matrix = typename Base::Matrix;
  using MatrixMaps = typename Base::MatrixMaps;
  using ConstMatrixMap = typename Base::ConstMatrixMap;
  using ConstMatrixMaps = typename Base::ConstMatrixMaps;

  TensorShapes GetOutputMatrixShapes(
      const TensorShapes& input_matrix_shapes) const final {}

  void ComputeMatrix(OpKernelContext* context, const ConstMatrixMaps& inputs,
                     MatrixMaps* outputs) final {};
```

Some of these items, such as the `LinearAlgebraOp` class, come from [`tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/512a3c3a6c0b36f6750394103b7eb316fe4ce853/tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.cc#L32).  However when I try to build my new op using [the instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#build_the_op_library), I get an error about that class.  How do I use this in my user ops?

Comment: I am coming from a place of relative ignorance about c++ stuff, so please be gentle.

Comment: I am trying to build with the python package (not bazel).  I'm on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Ah, you are correct about `Scalar`.  I will fix my question to be about `LinearAlgebraOp`, which is the error I'm getting.

Comment: @jdehesa I have tried to include the information you've requested.

Comment: Thank you, I think I see what's going on... You are trying to subclass `LinearAlgebraOp`, which is a template declared in [`tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.h#L40) - so you would need to add `#include "tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.h"` at the top of your file. However, that header does not appear to be among the ones included in the Python dist, I suppose because it's not required for basic C++ API usage.

Comment: That sounds like a "I need to compile tensorflow from source." :)

Comment: @jdehesa Do you think that following the [bazel install](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#compile_the_op_using_bazel_tensorflow_source_installation) instructions will help?

Comment: You could in theory copy include files from the source tree (or try to add paths in the source tree to the include path), in theory the symbols are in the library and should be linkable (I think?), but there's a lot of code generation and stuff during TF build so it may be challenging.

Comment: Well, Bazel _should_ work, it's kind of a pain but nowadays it tends to work. Since you are on Linux, it shouldn't give a lot of trouble.

Comment: @jdehesa, okie dokie.  I will go try out these suggestions.  If I find a clever solution I'll come back and post it here.  Cheers.

Comment: "try to add paths in the source tree to the include path" this seems to be successful.  Specifically, adding a symbolic link to the tensorflow r1.14 branch from the github source into my dist-packages/tensorflow/include files at the appropriate location has made the compiler not complain about including the linalg_common_ops header.  One error down.  :)

Comment: Nice :) You may also pass [`-I`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-i-dir) one or more times of gcc/clang to add search paths for includes, if you don't want to create symbolic links.

Comment: @jdehesa, the symbols aren't in the static library provided with the pip tensorflow distribution, it seems.  I'm going to compile tf from source and see what other static libraries materialize out of that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the class [`LinearAlgebraOp`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/512a3c3a6c0b36f6750394103b7eb316fe4ce853/tensorflow/core/kernels/linalg_ops_common.h#L40) from [user ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#compile_the_op_using_your_system_compiler_tensorflow_binary_installation), you'll need to export some new symbols in the shared libraries.  This means you'll need to [compile tensorflow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).

The compile-script framework that tensorflow uses is [bazel](https://bazel.build/) and the BUILD scripts list the various files and whatnot to be compiled and which functions to "advertise".  We need to "advertise" the files that the desired class is in.

First, we're going to change: `/tensorflow/core/BUILD` to tell bazel that our user ops will depend on these files.  Then, we'll change `tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD` to make them available.  Here's the git diff:

---

```
--- a/tensorflow/core/BUILD
+++ b/tensorflow/core/BUILD
@@ -1266,7 +1266,7 @@ cc_library(
     copts = tf_copts(),
     linkstatic = 1,
     visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
-    deps = [":framework"],
+    deps = [":framework", "//tensorflow/core/kernels:linalg_ops_common"],
     alwayslink = 1,
 )

--- a/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD
+++ b/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD
@@ -3317,7 +3317,7 @@ cc_library(
     name = "linalg_ops_common",
     srcs = ["linalg_ops_common.cc"],
     hdrs = ["linalg_ops_common.h"],
-    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
+    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
     deps = [
         "//tensorflow/core:framework",
         "//tensorflow/core:lib",
```

Great.  Now make sure that you list these dependencies in your [user op bazel BUILD file](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#compile_the_op_using_bazel_tensorflow_source_installation)

```
+    deps = ["//tensorflow/core/kernels:linalg_ops_common",],
```

Now, [compile tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source), and then [compile your module](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#compile_the_op_using_bazel_tensorflow_source_installation).  Now install your compiled custom version of tensorflow.  The `.so` file should now work on this install using the [usual user op import strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#use_the_op_in_python).